# Auto generation of serial no. based on two criteria in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, array-formulas

If column C has the word "Matured", and D has a valid date, then formula in column E should automatically generate a serial no., one higher than the previously existing serial numbers in column E.

[image: Auto generation of serial no. based on two criteria in Google Spreadsheet]

Here is the link to the Google Spreadsheet shared and filled with sample data :

> https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XdcKbxKvIOSFK37zwULZns6giE9ounHPS5iHrRFkvIk/edit#gid=1992300894

Needless to say, the status keep changing from Pending to Matured at different dates.

Comment: You could do this with a formula, but this would always re-assign invoice numbers when a quote matured with an earlier date than one of the ones which had already matured. So probably a script is the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You allow everyone to edit your spreadsheet? I hope you made a copy.

Anyway I wrote a script that should work.
To use it you put this formula into E2. `=genSerials(C2:D10, 1, "Matured", 2, true)`
The second argument is the column that contains the status. The third argument is the text that needs to be in the status column followed by the column to sort and then either true or false to indicate the sort order.

```
function genSerials(range, statusCol, statusText, dataToSortCol, ascending) {
  statusCol -= 1; dataToSortCol -= 1;

  var sorted = range.filter(function(row) {return row[statusCol] === statusText && row[dataToSortCol] !== "";}).map(function(row) {return row[dataToSortCol];});
  if(ascending) {
    sorted.sort(function(a,b) {if(a > b) return 1; else if(b > a) return -1; else return 0;});
  } else {
    sorted.sort(function(a,b) {if(a > b) return -1; else if(b > a) return 1; else return 0;});
  }

  var result = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < range.length; i++) {
    var row = range[i];
    if(row[statusCol] === statusText && row[dataToSortCol] !== "") {
      var idx = sorted.indexOf(row[dataToSortCol]);
      result.push([idx + 1]);
    } else {
      result.push([""]);
    }
  }

  return result;
}
```

Comment: Hi SpiderPIg It almost worked. Thank you! 
However, it seems to be following a decending order which it should not - e.g., once the quote no. 3 is Matured, and given a date, the script is rightly assigning it serial no. 5, so far so good. however, after that if quote no. 2 is also Mautred, and given a date, the serial no. 5 is now given to quote no. 2 snatching it from quote no. 3 - which obviously is unexpected.... i'm sorry, i hope i'm able to put across what i'm  trying to say, or may also see the above spreadsheet link i have put ur script there to check it. Thank u.

Comment: Do you want to serial number to be in the order in which the quotes matured? You could simply add the exact time to the date to achieve that.